# how to display map in google map API v3

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2

I have this sample code for google map api to search location. I can give the input but not able to display the map on browser. I tried various other codes in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-panel and other codes too but all of them have the same problem. I'm unable to short out the problem.
I tried to map the CSS code in javascript form.

Please help me out if something wrong with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Places search box</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
    <script>
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });
  var defaultBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8902, 151.1759),
      new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8474, 151.2631));
  map.fitBounds(defaultBounds);

  var input =(document.getElementById('target'));
  var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
  var markers = [];

  google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    for (var i = 0, marker; marker = markers[i]; i++) {
      marker.setMap(null);
    }

    markers = [];
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {
      var image = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
      };

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        icon: image,
        title: place.name,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
    }

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() {
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    searchBox.setBounds(bounds);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    <style>
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="panel">
      <input id="target" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    </div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error when you create the map object, you only give the type, but you left out the zoom and the center option, both required, you have to do it like these:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
```

[Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions)

Comment: its not working after giving all the required parameters in mapOptions

Comment: I dont have tried all your code because you said that the map doesnt show so I only make the corrections for that problem, maybe you have some other errors in the code

Comment: please sir, help me out in solving errors and make it work

Comment: The only thing the I can say is that you have to execute the code in a web server not the file directly

Answer (score 1):

You might also want to add some styling to the map-canvas container since it will be collapsed when the page loads;

```
  #map-canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
```